# Python algorithm for identification of low-level jets (meteorology)

Tags: python

A low-level jet is a local wind speed maximum near the surface. [Baas (2009)](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/2009JAMC1965.1) defined a low-level jet as follows:

> the lowest maximum of the wind speed profile in the lowest 500 m of the atmosphere that is at least both 2 m/s and 25% faster than the next minimum above (...) A minimum is neglected if the wind speed above that minimum increases less than 1 m/s before decreasing again to values lower than the wind speed of that minimum. When no minumum is present, the lowest value of the wind speed profile above the jet is taken as a minimum.

I have a 2D numpy array that contains wind speed values at several measurement heights and times. I've written an algorithm to identify for each time step whether the wind profile obeys this criterion. However, I think my code can be improved. Right now I'm using nested loops and a lot of if statements. Also I need to catch an index error because I need to check whether the 'next' value in the array is lower or higher.

I was hoping to get some feedback from more experienced programmers. Here's my code:

```
def findLLJ(wspd_matrix, time, hgt):
  '''Find low-level jets according to Peter Baas' algorithm
     input: wind speed matrix with time as first axis and height as second axis
            time and height arrays
     output: jet index array, jet height array, jet speed array
     use: jetidx,jethgt,jetspd = findLLJ(wsp_matrix,time,height)'''
  #Allocate output arrays:
  jet = np.zeros(time.shape,dtype=bool)
  jetspd = np.zeros(time.shape)
  jethgt = np.zeros(time.shape)
  #Shape of input array:
  ntime,nlev = wspd_matrix.shape
  #Consistency check:
  if not (ntime == len(time) and nlev == len(hgt)):
    raise Exception("Shapes of input arrays are not consistent")
  #Loop over all wind profiles at given times
  for t,prof in enumerate(wspd_matrix):
    maxflg = False
    minflg = False
    maxspd = 0.
    #Loop over all vertical points in the profile
    for i,x in enumerate(prof):
      #Find out whether vertical point is a maximum
      if np.any(x>(prof[i:]+2.5)) and np.any(x>1.25*prof[i:]) and x>maxspd:
        maxflg = True
        maxind = i
        maxspd = x
        print 'Maximum found at time',t,'and level',i,'with speed',x,'m/s'
      #Find out whether vertical point is a minimum
      try:
        if x<0.8*maxspd and x<maxspd-2.5 and x<prof[i+1] and not prof[i+2]<x:
          minflg = True
          minind = i
          minspd = x
          print 'Minimum found at time',t,'and level',i,'with speed',x,'m/s'
      except IndexError:
        if i == nlev-2 and x<0.8*maxspd and x<maxspd-2.5 and x<(prof[nlev-1]-1):
          minflg = True
          minind = i
          minspd = x
          print 'Minimum found at time',t,'and level',i,'with speed',x,'m/s'   
        else:
          minflg = True
          minind = nlev-1
          minspd = prof[nlev-1] # this should be changed to minumum of the profile, but that might return NaN, need to find an update for that.
          print 'No minumum found, using lowest value from profile'
      #Determine wheter a LLJ occured
      if maxflg and minflg:
        print 'Low-level jet found at time',t,'and height',hgt[maxind],'m with speed',maxspd,'m/s and minimum at',hgt[minind],'m with speed',minspd,'m/s'
        jet[t] = True
        jetspd[t] = maxspd
        jethgt[t] = hgt[maxind]
        break
      else:
        continue
  if maxflg and not minflg:
    print 'probably something wrong with NaNs'
  #End of loop, next profile...
  return jet,jethgt,jetspd
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

**Naming the variables**

- `wspd_matrix` would be much easier to read if it were called `wind_speed_matrix`
- `jetspd` would be much easier to read if it were called `jet_speed`
- `jethgt` would be much easier to read if it were called `jet_height`

**Remove the numeric values in the code**

`0.8` and `2.5` appear quite often in your code. It is hard for someone without a domain knowledge to know what they stand for. And if you have to change them for some reason, this is error-prone. Why not just naming them (`max_multiplier = 0.8` per example) at the beginning of the function ?

**Redundant condition**

```
if x<0.8*maxspd and x<maxspd-2.5
```

appears twice in your code. It represents a clear mathematical function :

```
if x<min(0.8*maxspd , maxspd-2.5)
```

which is much easier to read (and picture mentally)

**Redundant code**

Something needs to be done about this three prints :

```
print 'Maximum found at time',t,'and level',i,'with speed',x,'m/s'
print 'Minimum found at time',t,'and level',i,'with speed',x,'m/s' 
print 'Minimum found at time',t,'and level',i,'with speed',x,'m/s'
```

Maybe a

```
print_local_optimum_found(type_optimum, at_time, at_level, at_speed)
```

**Check the input**

```
if maxflg and not minflg:
    print 'probably something wrong with NaNs'
```

Why waiting until the end of the program to realize something wrong happened ? If you know NAs cause trouble, just check the presence of NAs before

**The algorithm itself**

It is hard to suggest improvements now with every piece of code in the same function. If you fix all this, such improvements will become much more readable!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have made a new version of my code which I think is more readable. However, it is still quite slow and I have the feeling that I could also use some suggestions for improving the approach to the problem. Splitting the code into several functions is a good step in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions, on the same line that RUser4512 outlined, will start focusing on a better naming of the variables. I'll add better naming for prof, nlev and ntime mostly so it's easier to know what they contain

Later, a Point class might be handy, with a function to determine if the point is maximum and another to know if its minimum

You can reduce the main chunk of code:

```
if np.any(x>(prof[i:]+2.5)) and np.any(x>1.25*prof[i:]) and x>maxspd:
    maxflg = True
    maxind = i
    maxspd = x
    print 'Maximum found at time',t,'and level',i,'with speed',x,'m/s'
  #Find out whether vertical point is a minimum
  try:
    if x<0.8*maxspd and x<maxspd-2.5 and x<prof[i+1] and not prof[i+2]<x:
      minflg = True
      minind = i
      minspd = x
      print 'Minimum found at time',t,'and level',i,'with speed',x,'m/s'
  except IndexError:
    if i == nlev-2 and x<0.8*maxspd and x<maxspd-2.5 and x<(prof[nlev-1]-1):
      minflg = True
      minind = i
      minspd = x
      print 'Minimum found at time',t,'and level',i,'with speed',x,'m/s'   
    else:
      minflg = True
      minind = nlev-1
      minspd = prof[nlev-1] # this should be changed to minumum of the profile, but that might return NaN, need to find an update for that.
      print 'No minumum found, using lowest value from profile'
  #Determine wheter a LLJ occured
  if maxflg and minflg:
    print 'Low-level jet found at time',t,'and height',hgt[maxind],'m with speed',maxspd,'m/s and minimum at',hgt[minind],'m with speed',minspd,'m/s'
```

To something like:

```
if point.is_maximum() and point.is_minimum():
    print 'Low-level jet found at time',t,'and height',hgt[point.maxind],'m with speed',point.maxspd,'m/s and minimum at',hgt[point.minind],'m with speed',point.minspd,'m/s'
```

Example of the point.is_maximum():

```
def is_maximum(self):
    if np.any(self.x>(self.prof[self.i:]+2.5)) and np.any(self.x>1.25*self.prof[self.i:]) and self.x>self.maxspd:
    self.maxflg = True
    self.maxind = i
    self.maxspd = x
    print 'Maximum found at time',self.prof.t,'and level',self.i,'with speed',self.x,'m/s'
```

Note you have to initialize the Point object with a few parameters, and is maybe sensible to create a Profile object as well

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I think I understand more or less what the point.class is supposed to do. However, it will take me some time to figure this out, since I've never worked with my own classes before... I'll try it